# Lua language: how use something similar to python list comprehensions

Tags: list, functional-programming, lua

I'm new to Lua and I was wondering if there are some compact way to define a `list`, a `metatable` in Lua as we do in Python:

```
lis = [i for i in set if i>0]
```

Any example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only similar thing I have seen is [this using code generation](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ListComprehensions).

Comment: although the lua stdlib does provide some functional programming utility, [filter](https://github.com/rrthomas/lua-stdlib/blob/origin/src/base.lua) is the one does this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua has no native list

However as @joachim pointed out, the are some hacks you can use to achieve it.

```
local comp = require 'comprehension' . new()
comp 'table(v,k for k,v in pairs(_1))' {[3]=5, [5]=7}
```

It would yield:

```
{[5]=3, [7]=5}
```

Notice that `comprehension` doesn't work in plain 5.2.x Lua. It requires Penlight Lua Libraries: http://stevedonovan.github.com/Penlight/api/index.html

You can also use [MetaLua](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MetaLua) or [LuaMacros](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaMacros)

Comment: Basically there's no _native_ way to do it?